# Is fallback function inheritable?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function, inheritance

I just have no means of testing it out myself right now.

```
contract A() {
     function() {
          throw;
     }
}
contract B is A() {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Browser-Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity), I compiled and deployed contract B with the following code:

```
contract A {
    function() {
        throw;
    }
}
contract B is A() {
}
```

I executed a `sendTransaction(...)` to B `(fallback)` and the Out Of Gas error was thrown.

So the answer is Yes.